# How to optimize pandas apply function

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use the function getKmers from this [post](https://github.com/krishnaik06/DNA-Sequencing-Classifier/blob/master/DNA%20Sequencing%20and%20applying%20Classifier.ipynb)

```
def getKmers(sequence, size=6):
    return [sequence[x:x+size].lower() for x in range(len(sequence) - size + 1)]

human_data['words'] = human_data.apply(lambda x: getKmers(x['sequence']), axis=1)
```

However my data set has over 50000 observations and when I ran this script my notebook crashed every time. How should I optimize?

One solution that I can think of is to divide the data set into pieces and run this code iteratively. I do not think this will work since apply() really just iterates through each row. I am not sure what is the problem here.

Comment: How many columns are in human_data? I think human_data.apply might be going through each column when in fact you just want to use the 'sequence' column

Comment: roughly 160 columns. Yes, I only need x['sequence']. Why is it going over each column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do it like this. You're unnecessarily going over each column by using apply that way, when you just want to use the sequence column.

```
human_data['words'] = human_data['sequence'].apply(getKmers)
```

Edit: While this is faster (you're forgoing running the lambda function), your original way was not going through each column, I mixed apply with applymap up.

Comment: Thank you and that makes sense. Is there any way that I can further optimize? I am able to run locally, but if I run it on a cloud server where I have limited ram it still does not work.

Comment: Could lower case the sequence prior to calling getKmers (remove the call to str.lower in getKmers
human_data['words'] = human_data['sequence'].apply(str.lower).apply(getKmers)